# $X_n = X \land n$ is square integrable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

If X is in $L^+(\Omega,\mathscr A, P)$ (denoting all nonnegative random variables). 
Why $X_n = X \land n$ is square integrable?

Comment: Is $P$ a bounded measure?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, a probability measure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|X\wedge n|\leq n,$ so $\int_{\Omega} |X\wedge n|^2\textrm{d}P\leq n^2P(\Omega)=n^2<\infty,$ if $P$ is a probability measure

Comment: Why $n^2$ is < $\infty$?

Comment: How can a finite number squared be infinite???

Comment: Presumably $n$ is a natural number?

Comment: couldn't be $n=\infty$? I'm reading that $lim_{n \to \infty}E[YX_n]$ = E[YX] by monotone convergence theorem. Therefore taking the limit it seems to me that n can also take value $ = \infty$

Comment: No. The point is exactly to modify $X$ to force it to be square integrable by cutting it off at $n$ and then letting $n$ tend to $\infty$. Your $n$ isn't ever actually $\infty$ - and either way, you don't need the case $n=\infty$ to apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou ok I get It. A last clarification if $X = \infty$, don't I need  $n = \infty$ for having the convergence $X_n \to X$?

Comment: Nope. Take $\omega\in (X=\infty)$, then $X_n(\omega)=n$ for every $n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} n=\infty$.